# run multiple for loop session simultaneously python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a list of input.
serverfarm = ''' 
server1 = 10.1  
server2 = 10.2  
server3 = 10.3  
server4 = 10.4  
server5 = 10.5  
server6 = 10.6  
server7 = 10.7  
server8 = 10.8  
server9 = 10.9  
server10 = 10.10    
server11 = 10.11    
server12 = 10.12    
server13 = 10.13    
server14 = 10.14    
server15 = 10.15    
server16 = 10.16    
server17 = 10.17    
server18 = 10.18    
server19 = 10.19    
server20 = 10.20    
'''
i do run a for loop for each server:

```
for server in serverfarm:<br>
.   ssh each server and do config # its take 5 min to complete a server.
```

the total time to complete the is list is 100 min. I need to reduce this time. I need to run multiple for loop simultaneously. i.e. in this case the for loop run for 5 or 10 servers at once.

let consider 10, in this case the script is taking just 10 min to complete the config on each server. I am not worry about the resource on my script server. just need to reduce the time at any cost.

OR if there is any way to run a master script which make copy of for loop in back-end and update the master script which return the value in 10 min.

Comment: Have you even tried to google this or solve yourself? Multithreading is what you probably look for.

Comment: perfect was looking for such type of knobs. thank you. checking...

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function that does the ssh and config part for a single server and run this with `multiprocessing.Process` somehow like this:

```
from multiprocession import Process

def configure_server(server):
   # Do your ssh and config stuff here

# List of processes
proc = []

# iterate your servers
for server in serverfarm:
    p = Process(target=configure_server, args=(server,))
    p.start()
    proc.append(p)

# Block main thread until all processes are finished
for p in proc:
    p.join()
```

For more details on `Process` or other multiprocessing related stuff have a look at the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class).